# What is the name of the probability distribution of ROC-AUC when training machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc

When training ML models like neural networks they are random initialized. That has the effect that the results (ROC-AUC for example) are influenced by random effect. When I train them multiple times they form a probability distribution which can not be less than 0 and not be more than 1 (in case of ROC-AUC). What is the name of this distribution? I tried to draw some examples below.

[image]

Thanks
Philip

Comment: No specific name for the distribution of AUCs. By the way, the distribution can be normal or any other renown distribution, depends on data and paramters of the learning method.

Comment: AUC was just an example for metrics that are between 0 and 1. Like F1, Accuracy and so on.
IMO normal is not exact because a normal distribution can have infinite values. AUC can be 1 at max.

Comment: You're right. But, I mean normal as an example. It can be truncated normal distribution. By the way, the main subject is this is a distribution and not more!

Comment: Maybe a Beta distribution?